# Как найти строки без определенных символов?

Tags: строки, pascal

Нужно определить сколько строчных и прописных букв "s" и знаков "=" встречается в заданном тексте. Вывести строки, в котором эти символы отсутствуют.

Как мне реализовать проверку текста и как распознать строки где нет этих знаков?

на сей момент

```
program four;
var
  i : integer;
  LowerS, UpperS, Equals: Integer;
  MyString : string;
begin
  LowerS := 0;
  UpperS := 0;
  Equals := 0;

  Write('Enter text to scan: ');
  ReadLn( MyString );

  for i := 1 to Length(MyString) do
  begin      
    case ( MyString[i] ) of
      'S' : Inc(UpperS); 
      's' : Inc(LowerS); 
      '=' : Inc(Equals);
    end;  
  end;
  if (UpperS + LowerS + Equals) = 0 then
    WriteLn('No valid characters found')
  else
    WriteLn(Format('S: %d s: %d =: %d', [UpperS, LowerS, Equals]));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: @JavaFan, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @JavaFan, ну текст, видимо, из файла надо читать. Assign, Reset... "Где нет этих знаков" вы уже проверяете, разве нет?

Comment: andru2013,  я так понял, что вам надо текст разбить на строки и узнать где нет этих знаков: 'S', 's', '!', так? Или нет?

Comment: Просто никому непонятно,  на какой вопрос вам надо подготовить ответ, вот в чем дело. Поэтому на ваш вопрос я поставил тревогу вида "этот вопрос должен быть закрыт".

Answer (score 0):

Эта программа ищет всё букви 'а' (русс.) и пробел ' ' имеет значения язык,  если вы поймёте этот код вы поймёте что нужно заменить, а что пачти полностью дублировать (в предпоследной строке буква ' ' обозначает букву которую нужно найти).

```
program name;

var s: String;

function a1(s1:String; c1:Char): Integer;
var i,k: Integer;
begin
  k:=0;
  for i:=1 to Length(s1) do
    if s1[i]=c1 then k:=k+1;
  a1:=k;
end;

begin
  read(s);
  writeln(a1(s,'а'));
  writeln(a1(s,' '));
end.
```